# "interval" parameter is not working in Consul

Tags: distributed-computing, consul, service-discovery

I'm trying to use consul at my workplace. I set interval for a check as "1s". But, interval parameter is not working properly and have no ideas what's wrong. As you can see, The interval is very weird, way apart from my setting.

[image]

I'm trying to run this "check" in a client (I'm testing with one-server and two-client .The OS is CentOS, and local ENV.)

```
{"check": {"name": "ping",
"args": ["ping", "-c1", "google.com"], "interval": "1s", "timeout": "1s"}}
```

and This is the setting for the client where the check is running.

```
{
   "disable_remote_exec":false,
   "server":false,
   "start_join":[
      "192.168.111.146" (server's ip)
   ]
}
```

the command I'm using for starting is this. and connecting to server is fine.

```
consul agent -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent1 -bind=192.168.111.148 -enable-script-checks=true -config-dir=/etc/consul.d
```

I checked logs inside /var/log and nothing special there. Could you guess what the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Actually It was working, I just misunderstood.
by running the command "consul monitor -log-level=debug" in the client.
I was able to check all the logs running every single second like this.

[image]